# Verifier or Verificator

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, nouns

We are building a software to [verify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_verification) the correctness and the safety of computer programs,

I would like to know the name of this software should be a "program verifier" or a "program verificator".

Comment: Which dictionaries did you find "verificator" in?

Comment: You can simply refer to that as the "program verification software [package]".

Comment: @Eilia - Careful, "software" and especially "package" used this way are quite likely to be taken as commercial software, as opposed to custom software, which is what OP was talking about.  Maybe "program" or "suite" would work a little better in your phrase.

Comment: @aparente001, since the program is not a good candidate (due to duplication), so my suggestion changes to "program verification suite", not a single word but a working one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I work in the software industry. Verificator is not a word I've ever come across. While I can understand why it might be a candidate on your list (because it's close to the noun "verification"), the word you're looking for is "verifier".

One side observation too - one would not normally say "a software", except in a context such as "a software program" or "a software suite". Just "software".

Comment: English language learners (ELLs) often want something countable.  *A piece of software* maybe satisfy them. / By the way, it's good to cite relevant personal experience, as you did, but it's also good to get in the habit of citing some reliable source.

Comment: It's also good to get into the habit of looking at the question being asked, which was whether it was verifier or verificator.

Comment: Sure.  The other thing was tangential. / what I mean is, you'll get more upvotes on your answers if you include a link and a quote -- in this case, a dictionary definition of "verifier," or a technical article talking about "verifier," would strengthen your answer.  I'm sharing this tip because you're a new contributor.  Welcome to ELU!  Not the most warm and fuzzy site in the system but I learn a lot here.